# FrontController: No reconoce el controlador principal

Tags: mvc, composer, php8

Estoy migrando un antiguo sistema, donde implemento composer, PSR's y demas. Mi primer problema es cuando estoy creando el "FrontController", el cual me regresa un erro en especifico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi `composer.json` es el siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "edgargc026/taller-mecanico",
    "description": "Refactorizando un proyecto antiguo con buenas practicas de programacion",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "edgargc026",
            "email": "edgargc_26@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app",
            "Config\\": "config"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

Para cargar las clases y use los siguientes:

`index.php` donde hago el FrontController y toda la magia sucede.

```php
<?php
use App\Controllers\ErrorController;
use App\Controllers\HomeController;
use Config\Database;

require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "./bootstrap.php";

const baseUrl = "http://backendphp.test/TallerMecanico/";
const defaultController = "HomeController";
const actionDefault = "index";

function showError(){
  $error = new ErrorController;
  $error->errorView();
}

if(isset( $_GET['controller'])){
  $nameController = $_GET['controller'].'Controller';
} else if( !isset( $_GET['controller'] ) && !isset( $_GET['action'])){
  $nameController = defaultController;
} else {
  showError();
  exit();
}

if( class_exists($nameController) ){
  $controller = new $nameController();
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controller, $_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $controller->$action();
  }elseif ( !isset( $_GET['controller']) && !isset( $_GET['action']) ){
    $actionDefault = actionDefault;
    $controller->$actionDefault();
  } else {
    showError();
    echo "Primer fallo";
  }
} else {
  showError();
  echo "Segundo fallo";
}
```

Y el archivo `bootstrap.php` donde hago la autocarga:

```php
<?php
function controllersAutoload($className){
  include 'Controllers/' .$className .'.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('controllersAutoload');
```

Anexo tambien mi `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 http://backendphp.test/TallerMecanico/error/

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

Sin embargo, el resultado de todo esto es el error que puse al principio. Debuggeando un rato (metiendo `var_dump()` como si no hubiera mañana), me di cuenta que tiene el nombre de la constante `const HomeController` pero esta no entra al segundo `if`, la cual es `if(class_exist($nameController)){}` ¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: hiciste el dump?? `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Comment: Si, hice el dump anteriormente.

Comment: despues de los cambios

Comment: no se ve que hay dentro de controller

Comment: Dentro del controller solo hay un metodo que imprime un `Al toque rey, has entrado a la pagina`

Comment: puedes mostrarlo falta inforamacion

Comment: tienes en github lo que has desarrollado??? para poder evaluar la instalación que tienes

Comment: yo implemente el autload en esta clase: https://github.com/arcanisgk/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler y me funciona perfectamente; deberias de copiarte pero como te decía depende de tu setup de tu servidor y de tu configuracion por que en lugar de `'./vendor/'` yo uso `__DIR__.'\..\vendor\autoload.php'` y por hay puede andar el error, además el error reportado por tu php es eso que no encuentra el archivo `HomeController.php` ...